# Checkbox code not showing checked but it change the checked value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

Hi I been struggling with this issue. I need to load the state of a checkbox so I implement the next code:

```js
$rowannex.find('.first').prop( "checked", true);
$rowannex.find('.second').attr("disabled", true);
$rowannex.find('.print').prop("checked",true);
```

```html
<td class="text-center">{!! Form::radio('first', '1', false, array('class'=>'first')) !!}</td>
<td class="text-center">{!! Form::checkbox('second_costocultivoagricola_tabla_anexos', '1', false, array('class'=>'second')) !!}</td>
<td class="text-center">{!! Form::checkbox('print_costocultivoagricola_tabla_anexos', '1', false, array('class'=>'print', 'disabled')) !!}</td>
```

The problem is that the .prop is working, it changes the .first to checked, it changes to disabled the .second and it changes to checked the .print but this one don't show as checked.

Im using laravel and JQuery as you can see and for the css im using bootstrap. I try in Chrome, Safari and Opera without any changes. Also I try the .attr still the same issue. Sorry for the English it is not my first lenguage I hope someone knows what the problem is, thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify "I need to load the state a checkbox"?

Comment: Sure I need to set it checked or not checked depending on a value store in a database

Comment: Is the `.print` disabled when you try to change it to checked?  Have you tried this logic without it being disabled, if so?

Comment: Like @Taplar already says, change **disabled** by **readonly** if you want to change the state.

Comment: @Taplar I need it to be disable for default I though that too and I try to enable it from code and then changing it to checked. The result was the input enable and with its property checked true but not showing as checked

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately I find the problem there was another .js that reload the elements so I change my function to this file and it work. It was really simple after all.